# Count occurrences of midnight between datetimes

Tags: python

Is there a native facility or third party library for python that can count the number of occurrences of a time (in particular the number of midnights) between two datetimes?

It is not sufficient to count the number of days because the datetimes might not have the same time component, so you end up with the kind of intervals shown in this example:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

dt1 = dt(2014,05,21,23)
dt2 = dt(2014,05,22,01)
i1 = dt2-dt1
print(i1) # 1 midnight but 2 hours

dt3 = dt(2014,05,21,01)
dt4 = dt(2014,05,22,23)
i2 = dt4-dt3 # 1 midnight but 1 day + 22 hours
print(i2)
```

Comment: It is sufficient actually.  The number of midnights is the same as the number of  times the date has incremented.  So subtract the dates (without times).  In both your examples I see 21 going to 22 and it's quite simple... one midnight each.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the time component of both datetimes to the same time, then do the difference.

```
def midnights(dt1, dt2):
    dt1 = dt1.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
    dt2 = dt2.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
    return (dt2 - dt1).days
```

Comment: Thank you Mark for pointing out the obvious :) I had originally tried this approach when they were in different timezones, but if I put them in the same timezone and use your approach, the problem is easily solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Use `.date()` for the difference:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

def count_midnights(dt1, dt2):
    return (dt2.date() - dt1.date()).days
```

This way you get:

```
>>> dt1 = dt(2014,05,21,23)
>>> dt2 = dt(2014,05,22,01)
>>> print count_midnights(dt1, dt2)
1

>>> dt3 = dt(2014,05,21,01)
>>> dt4 = dt(2014,05,22,23)
>>> print count_midnights(dt3, dt4)
1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a bit crazy alternative, mostly FYI, - you can use a nice [`Delorean`](http://delorean.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) third-party:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
import delorean
from delorean import stops


dt1 = dt(2014,05,21,23)
dt2 = dt(2014,05,22,01)

print sum(1 for stop in stops(start=dt1, stop=dt2, freq=delorean.HOURLY) 
          if stop.datetime == stop.midnight())
```